# How to read a comma delimited file and output results by 3 in a single row

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I have a text file that contains more than 25k records which looks like this in a single line:

```
cr:121,cr:122,cr:123,cr:124,cr:221,cr:222,cr:223,cr:224,cr:225,cr:321, and so on..
```

I would like to create a batch file to read the comma separated values and output them in a new file by batch of 3.

Expected Result: newfile.txt

```
cr:121,cr:122,cr:123
cr:124,cr:221,cr:222
cr:223,cr:224,cr:225
cr:321
```

I searched the site but all I can find is batch commands for FOR statements that tackles files with multiple rows, not a single line.

I am currently trying

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("algtest_extract.txt") do (
echo %%a %%b %%c %%d )
```

but this only works for files with multiple lines. It gives me the first 4 values then exits.

Comment: @Ruben_PH you've mentioned notepad++ in tags. Your file could be easily splitted with regular expressions in notepad++. Do you want to have the batch or one-time splitting in notepad++ would be enough?

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov I am not that proficient in using regex but yes, I just need the file to be split either in batch or notepad++

Comment: Are the field values always of the same width? And what is the maximal line length?

Comment: @aschipfl no, they get longer as the record goes on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++ press `Ctrl+H`, set Search Mode in `"Regular expression"`, then use search pattern

```
([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),
```

and repace with

```
\1\n
```

**UPD**

use search pattern `((?:[^,]+,){500})` if you want to use 500 elements instead of 3.
The commas in the end of each line could be replaced using search pattern `,$`

Comment: I was actually working on this one, this works but 'by batch of 3' is just a sample, what i really need is by batch of 500 and adding {500} on the search pattern seems not supported in notepad++.

Comment: @Ruben_PH check out another regular expression

Comment: It works. My mistake is that I am putting the {500} outside the parenthesis like so ((?:[^,]+,)){500}.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I could not resist to write a batch script for accomplishing your task. Given script is called `reshape.bat`, provide the input text file as a command line argument, like this:

```cmd
reshape.bat "algtest_extract.txt"
```

To store the output data into another file, say `algtest_reshaped.txt`, do this:

```cmd
reshape.bat "algtest_extract.txt" > "algtest_reshaped.txt"
```

Here is the code (see all the explanatory remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (file to process; `%~1` means first argument)
set "_COL=3"    & rem // (number of columns in the output data)
set "_SEP=,"    & rem // (separator character for input and output data)
set "_PAD="     & rem // (if defined, fill up last row with empty cells)

rem // Read from file:
< "%_FILE%" call :PROCESS

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
    rem // Initialise variables:
    set "REST=" & rem // (remaining text string after the first separator)
    set "LINE=" & rem // (row collector for line/row to output)
    set "IDX=0" & rem // (column counter for output data)
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:READ
    rem // Read some text, 1023 characters/bytes at most:
    set "STR=" & set /P STR=""
    rem // Terminate loop if no more data are available:
    if not defined STR goto :END
    rem // Precede with potential remainder from previous loop:
    set "STR=!REST!!STR!"
:PARSE
    rem // Extract everything behind the first separator:
    if defined STR set "REST=!STR:*%_SEP%=!"
    rem // No separator had been found, so read more text:
    if "!REST!"=="!STR!" goto :READ
    rem // Extract part in front of first separator:
    for /F "delims=%_SEP%" %%I in ("ITEM=!STR!") do set "%%I"
    rem // Increment column counter:
    set /A "IDX+=1" & if !IDX! lss %_COL% (
        rem // Output line/row not yet complete, so go on assembling:
        set "LINE=!LINE!%_SEP%!ITEM!"
    ) else (
        rem // Output line/row complete, hence return it:
        echo(!LINE:*%_SEP%=!%_SEP%!ITEM!
        rem // Reset row collector and column counter:
        set "LINE=" & set /A "IDX=0"
    )
    rem // Keep on parsing using the remainder:
    set "STR=!REST!" & goto :PARSE
:END
    rem // Return potential remaining data:
    if defined _PAD (set /A "IDX=_COL-IDX-1") else (set /A "IDX=0")
    set "LINE=!LINE!%_SEP%!REST!"
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%IDX%) do set "LINE=!LINE!%_SEP%"
    if defined LINE echo(!LINE:*%_SEP%=!
    endlocal
```